# Is there a command in macOS terminal that can recursively search a string in all files under current directory (including sub-directory)?

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

I want to know if there is a command in macOS, similar to the `grep -r <target-string>` in Linux, that can list all lines containing `<target-string>` in files under current directory (including files in subdirectories).

Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQXpk.png)

Comment: macOS has grep.  `grep -r <target-string> .`

Comment: @gman But the behaviour is different. When I type in `grep -r <target-string>`, it returns `grep: warning: recursive search of stdin` and then the command hang in there.

Comment: You need to provide the path, just like gman did `.`

Comment: @Kaiido @gman Thanks guys! Finally find out the problem! `.` is the key... orz